# Flash AS3 javascript popup on Safari

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to do a popup window that is sized at 300x200 when clicking a button using the following code

```
var jscommand:String = "window.open('http://www.mydomainexample.com','win','height=200,width=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');"; 
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);"); 
navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

It opens up fine except on Safari 3.
Has anyone ever encountered this and can give me a pointer?

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: is your safari blocking popups?

Comment: have you determined it is flash related? Does executing your javascript from an HTML context work in safari 3?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using `ExternalInterface`? I've had good success with it in the past

`ExternalInterface.call("functionName", argument);`

Comment: Thanks rson.
Yup that's what I had initially. Doesn't work either.

Comment: did you have your javascript client-side, or as a string inside of the Flash document?